# Update fields in table in PostGIS database by joining attribute by field value from a layer

Tags: qgis, postgis, layers, table, update

I have a table in my PostGIS database. Its geometric objects I loaded in to my QGIS project as layer where I can edit them. In this layer (layer A) there are features with null values in some fields. I have another layer B with features containing specific values in these fields. I like to update the layer A with the values of the layer B by joining the segment_id.

With the tool "Join attributes by field value" from the toolbox I do not have the option to update an existing table. I can just save the output as a new table in my database.

Is there another way to update a table in the database with values from the attributes of a layer?

Comment: Are both 'layers' in PostgreSQL? If so, run an `UPDATE` through the *DB Manager* (or the DB client of your choice). If not, import the other first - you can do that through QGIS via drag'n'drop in the *Browser* panel.

Comment: @geozelot: what do you mean with drag'n'drop in the _Browser_ panel? How to do that?

Comment: Drag and drop it: https://imgur.com/a/2yZYr3P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import table B to PostgreSQL and:

```
UPDATE test.table_a AS a
SET 
    attr1 = b.attr2,
    attr2 = b.attr2,
    attr3 = b.attr3
FROM test.table_b as b
WHERE a.segment_id = b.segment_id
```

See: [How to do an update + join in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869592/how-to-do-an-update-join-in-postgresql)

[image]

Comment: Thank you BERA! That means that I do it directly with the _DB Manager_ (and SQL) and there is no tool to handle it with the layers. Probably it is the easiest way anyway to do it with the _DB Manager_ but I liked to know another way because in my case there are many attributes to update.

Answer (score 2):

You could join layer B  with layer A on segment_id (layerproperties -> joins). Then you can open the attributetable and sort the field with missing values in table A. Then select all rows with missing values and use the fieldcalculator (start editing and open the combobox in the attributetable to select the field you want to update, then click on the E symbol) In the fieldcalculator choose fields and values and apply to selected rows.